# Using erase() in a for loop only erasing first line

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, line, erase

I am trying to use `std::string::erase()` in a `for` loop to delete a line at a time from a string, however it only deletes the first line.

Why does it only delete the first line?

```
Using namespace std;
String = "Adam\nBen\nCallum\nDennis\n"
for(i=0; i<3; i++){
  size_t endofstring = string.find("\n");
  string.erase(0,endofstring);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a tag for the language you are using? It's c++ I guess?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the second argument of `erase()` is a length, while you are passing an index, so it removes everything up to, but not including, the `\n`.

As per your expectation, it seems you want to remove the `\n` as well, so use `index+1`:

```
string.erase(0, endofstring+1)
```

For more reference, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/